# Restore functionality of Escape key in Finder (Mavericks)

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos, accessibility

It's always been possible to remove focus from all selected files in Finder by pressing the <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> key. It would appear that this is no longer possible in OS X Mavericks. I navigate the Finder entirely via keyboard and using <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> is something I do quite frequently.

I've looked at nearly every preference pane I could think of as well as the contents of `com.apple.finder.plist`, `com.apple.systempreferences.plist`, and `com.apple.universalaccess.plist`, but no luck so far (or I'm just not seeing it).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this got replaced by the menu item **Edit > Select All**. That doesn’t seem to like being set to `Esc` in System Preferences, but perhaps that’s something to dig into?

Comment: @alexwlchan I don't quite follow. I'm trying to select zero files, not all files.

Comment: No kidding! Sounds nice, but I've never, in many years, seen or heard of this … in Finder. In some apps, yes, but ...

Comment: @JeromeDahdah: I fail at typing. If you hold down the `Opt` key, then **Select All** becomes **Deselect All**. I assume that’s what you’re looking for, but I can't find an easy way to bind that to `Esc`.

Comment: @alexwlchan Ah, cool, I didn't know that shortcut was available. I'll have a look into it, thanks.

Comment: Alright, my progress so far. As @alexwlchan mentions, it's impossible to bind `esc` in **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts**. I've added `cmd`+`esc` as a shortcut for **Deselect All**, but that's far from ideal. I've now figured out that it is possible to remove `cmd` from the shortcut by editing `com.apple.finder.plist`. This can be done either by using the XCode plist editor or by using `defaults write com.apple.finder.plist NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Deselect all" -string "\\U238b"` in Terminal.app.

Comment: Problem with the previous comment: in both cases, the system resets the file `com.apple.finder.plist` and restores the old shortcut after a minute or so (also not sure if `\\U238b` is the proper character as I haven't been able to actually test it). I've read that Mavericks now caches preferences and that the only way to overwrite them is by using `defaults write`, but that is not working. No clue how to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get it to work. Even if I do `defaults read` I get `"Deselect all" = "\\\\U238b";` but it still does not work with <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> and only with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd>. Tried restarting System Preferences and Finder. No dice. I really want there to be a solution. Using a keyboard remapping app isn't great because it affects the WHOLE application and not just when that menu item is available.

Answer (score 6):

Right shortcut is: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

In System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcut 
you can create your custom shortcut, only for Finder if you want (You must use at least combination of cmd or option or maiusc + another key).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is the correct answer. `⌘` + `⌥` + `A` = `Deselect All` in Finder.

Comment: @MathiasBynens The question is how to restore that functionality to the `Esc` key, which is not possible with this answer. Please see also my further comments below my original question.

Comment: Instead of the `Esc` key you can use `F19` on a wide apple keyboard, it's located like the `Esc` key, just on the other side, it's almost as comfortable.

Answer (score 5):

Download and install the free & excellent KeyRemap4MacBook software:
https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

Open its main preference window then choose the Misc & Uninstall tab

Follow the steps described at

https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html.en#privatexml

using this snippet as the content for private.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

  <item>
    <name>Finder: Escape to Deselect All (Cmd-Opt-D)</name>
    <identifier>private.app_finder_escape_to_Deselect_All</identifier>
    <only>FINDER</only>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
  </item>

</root>
```

After pressing the ReloadXML find the new mapping and turn it on, and enjoy.

PS. Don't forget to remove any custom keyboard shortcut from Finder's `Deselect All…` from System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/App Shortcuts/Finder/Deselect All… if you tried solving this problem this way.

Comment: Now Escape key can't escape from file renaming :/ Isn't it great to have a computer which talks to you (but otherwise it's becoming crappier and crappier with every update)?

Comment: Hm, you're right, I hadn't encountered that one yet. I'll leave this marked as accepted for now, as it's currently the closest to a full solution. And yeah, it sucks, but I figure they did this so that it doesn't conflict with exiting Finder's fullscreen mode. It makes sense, but it sucks.

Comment: Also, you can't escape from Finder's (normal+contextual) menus with plain Escape, but Command-Escape seems to work.

Comment: Found a more critical issue: when dragging a file you can't escape if you change your mind. Basically you have to drop the file back into its source window or risk dropping it somewhere you don't want it to go. I think I'll have to deactivate the shortcut and revoke the 'accepted' status from this answer. Sorry about that. I appreciate your efforts. I wish Apple would just fix this.

Comment: No worries, I also don't really like my own "solution". I tried to create a shortcut in BetterTouchTool with two actions (first triggering `Esc` to leave menu/renaming/whatever, then triggering deselecting), but it didn't accept the `Esc` key as a shortcut (just like in system preferences). Maybe redefining F19 as Esc, and Esc as Deselect? ... I hate when Apple fixes working things. FTFF!!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)… :)

[image: Escaping Finder selection with Keyboard Maestro]

Comment: Royaljerry, please could you expand your answer to explain the contents of the screen shots. This would help others find your answer and help those who have difficulty understanding the embedded images.

Answer (score 2):

As a solution to this Problem I use the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if selection is [] then
        tell application "System Events" to key code 36 using control down
    else
        set selection to []
    end if
end tell
```

The script implements the following logic:

- If there is no file or folder selected in Finder then this script tries to escape from a possible rename operation if there is one (beeps if there is none).
- If there are files or folders selected in Finder then this script deselects them.

I use FastScripts from Red Sweater Software to remap the escape key in Finder to this script. FastScripts installs a script menu in the menubar and is free for use with up to 10 scripts.

With both parts together the behaviour of the escape key is similar to the escape key behaviour in older macOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great utility for mapping new shortcuts… http://www.keyboardmaestro.com

PS thanks for the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>